# PCI RAID controller compatibility

Tags: raid, pci, hardware-raid

Recently I've been thinking of buying a cheap RAID controller. I'm not experienced at all, and just want to mess around; nothing business affiliated, no specific expectations.

The controllers I've been thinking of buying are either [PCI 2.2](http://www.vesalia.de/e_sii3114.htm) or [PCI 2.3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BZB29E) compliant, while the motherboard I plan on using is PCI 2.2 compliant (a Gigabyte GA-8PE800 rev 1.1).

So, my questions are:

1. Would the PCI 2.3 RAID controller be compatible with my motherboard?
2. Similarly, would the PCI 2.2 one be fine with a PCI 2.3/3.0 motherboard?
3. Is there anything else (other than the PCI version) to be considered (in terms of compatibility)?

Comment: Generally speaking you can place a higher level PCI card in a lower level slot, but not all lower level cards will work in higher level slots due to missing +5v line in 2.2 and higher slots. There is generally no compatibility issues after PCI 2.2

Comment: So I might run into issues with the 2.2 card and a 3.0 slot, while the 2.3 card should do fine with 2.2, 2.3 and even 3.0 slots. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you may run into trouble with some 2.1 or older cards that require the +5v bus to operate, not all do, in fact very few require it. From version 2.2 on, there is essentially no compatibility issues to be concerned with.

Comment: @acejavelin It sounds like you've got the answer. Could you post that as the answer below so we can mark this as a good answer?

Comment: @music2myear There you go... hopefully the OP will accept and upvote if it answers their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you can place a higher level PCI card in a lower level slot, but not all lower level cards will work in higher level slots due to missing +5v line in 2.2 and higher slots. There is generally no compatibility issues after PCI 2.2

You may run into trouble with some 2.1 or older cards that require the +5v bus to operate, not all do, in fact very few require it. From version 2.2 on, there is essentially no compatibility issues to be concerned with.